# The argument type 'TextTheme' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter, migration, flutter-layout, material-design

I have a `TabBar` in which I am using **labelColor**, I am trying to migrate `accentTextTheme`, Currently my `labelColor` is LIKE THIS:

```
labelColor:
Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.headline4.color,
```

I trying to migrate `accentTextTheme` like this from the **flutter docs**.

**Code before migration:**

```
TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.headline1;
```

**Code after migration:**

```
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
TextStyle style = theme.textTheme.headline1.copyWith(
  color: theme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
),
```

but when I try to implement it I get this error:

**The argument type 'TextTheme' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.**

Is there any way to migrate this without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`labelColor` takes a `Color` and you are providing `TextStyle`,

```dart
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    TextStyle style = theme.textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
      color: theme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar( // just test for warring 
            labelColor: style.color,
            tabs: [],
          ),
          Text(
            "asda",
            style: style,
          ),
```

does it solve the issue?

Comment: Yea, it seems to work. Thank You.

Comment: Glad to help you out.